# unable to download all of ubuntu 20.xx over wifi. The file(.iso) is 2.7 gig but only get to 1.6 gig and crash every try

Tags: 20.04, firefox, files, downloads, system

unable to download all of ubuntu 20.xx over wifi using firefox. The file(.iso) is 2.7 gig but only get to 1.6 gig and crash every try.The satellite System down is 5.5 megs and up is 6 megs.system with 600+ lat, crash at 300 megs of download, restart, crash, restart then crash....once got to 1.9 gigs then crash... Is there a way to hold the system open while downloading?

Comment: There are many reasons why this could be happening and none of them related to ubuntu. Atmospherics; close to your download limits; not a clear view of the sky from your dish etc. What makes you believe this is ubuntu related and therefore asked here?

Comment: I suggest that you try **torrent** instead of a simple 'download'. That way small chunks are received and merged, and there is a checksum test in the process, so it is very likely to work. If the torrent fails, please check if there is enough drive space for the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu to download, I would suggest using a command line tool like aria2 to do the download.

First, install aria2 by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install aria2
```

Next, use the `aria2c` command to download the file:

```
cd ~/Downloads
aria2c -x5 https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04.2.0/ubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64.iso
```

This will use 5 connections to do the download. Aria2 has the ability to resume downloading in case the download fails at some point. If you need to, you can run the command again and it will resume downloading the remaining portion of the file.

Also, don't forget to [verify your file](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#3-download-checksums-and-signatures) when you are done.